# Outlook add-in needs file explorer to run

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have made an outlook add-in that saves e-mails to a document folder through

`mailItem.SaveAs(@"\\\mysite\mylist\randomnumber.msg")`.

Sometimes, the email doesn't get saved, and show below error.

> Error:The operation failed.

If I open a windows explorer to `\\mysite\mylist\`, then all subsequent emails are saved.

This is a very peculiar issue!!

My workaround is to 'forcibly' open a connection to Sharepoint and if there's an error, well deal with it manually:

```
string[] ss = Directory.GetFiles('\\mysite\mylist\');
```

and if it doesn't work:

```
Process.Start('\\mysite\mylist\');
```

So, I wonder if someone has come up with that issue and other workarounds.